# Why can't we call a function from a function with a default argument?

Tags: c++, function, default-arguments

The program:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(void (*bar)()){ bar(); };

void foo(int a = 5)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{ 
    foo(foo); //Error
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc3fc6cc6faa3f98)**

I expected that eventually `foo(5)` will be called. In contrast, the following program works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(void (*bar)()){ bar(); };

void foo()
{
    std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{ 
    foo(foo); //OK
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eac4d53315cc2ade)**

Could you explain that difference?

Comment: Having a default argument doesn't alter the signature of the function. Also the compiler adds the default argument at the callsite if you don't provide one, not when you're trying to form a pointer to the function.

Comment: @Praetorian So how can I call the function in the first case?

Comment: I don't think you can. The information about the default argument is lost when you go through the pointer to function, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Default parameters do not exist after compilation. They are just shorthand and are inserted during compilation. Therefore they cannot be used at run time

Comment: @EdHeal Does it specify in the Standar explicitly?

Comment: @Praetorian It's a bit unclear how actually name lookup works in the first case? It found two function with the name foo. How does it perform overload resolution?

Answer (score 2):

In the first example although foo has default argument its type is void (bar*)(int). Having the default argument makes it possible to call foo without specifying the argument value explicitly, but there is still an int argument. Simply its value is automatically populated(during compilation).